# Does anybody knows a replacement for TorrentSpy?

Tags: windows, bittorrent

I've used [TorrentSpy](http://torrentspy.sourceforge.net) since 2004 and it does a pretty good job but it is very slow with torrent files that have hundreds or thousands of files. Does anyboy knows a better tool for the same job in XP?

If you didn't know it, TorrentSpy show the data contained in a torrent file in a readable way: URL's tracker, number of files, its size, number of complete and incomplete downloaders, etc.

**Edit:** What I want is something that can be used from explorer right-clicking in the torrent file, like [MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net) does with media files.

**Edit 2:** TorrentSpy is **not** a torrent client. It just show the information inside the torrent in a legible way. Just as MediaInfo did not play a media file, just show information about it.

[image: general]

[image: Files]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried Bit Torrent or UTorrent?

Comment: See [Comparison of BitTorrent clients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_BitTorrent_clients).

Answer (score 0):

uTorrent is by far the best client to use.

Update:
Ok I'm with you now.
You want to inspect the .torrent file, not suggestions on which client to use/is the best.
uTorrent can do that but only after you start the download. i.e. checking the tracker/file/peers tabs.
If you want that kind of functionality from the Windows context menu (right click from Explorer) there may be a program available, alternatively why not just edit the file type associations and create a new verb action so that you can run torrentspy from the context menu, with say a verb such as "Inspect"?

Comment: Without a question, but I need something else: a tool that show me information about the torrent.